# Microphone Input plays Sound Ouput, Sound Output is linked to Microphone Settings

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, microphone, alsamixer

I have been trying to fix some audio issues since downloading Debian 11 on my laptop, which has both an in-built speaker and a microphone. I use earbuds that don't have a built-in microphone. When playing sound (either via earbuds or via laptop speaker) it registers also as input into the microphone, and there's reduced sound in the right ear without being imbalanced in settings.

Here are some screenshots of pavucontrol, alsamixer, and my settings
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

here if I unlock the two channels or I switch the port to just "Microphone" audio input in my earbuds doesn't work anymore. There's no listed input devices when my earbuds aren't plugged in

Output of

> arecord -l

```
 **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC215 Analog [ALC215 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC215 Alt Analog [ALC215 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of

> lsmod | grep snd

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
snd_sof_pci            24576  0
snd_sof_intel_byt      24576  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   102400  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_hda_codec_realtek   163840  1
snd_sof               139264  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_skl           180224  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_sof
snd_soc_sst_dsp        36864  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    45056  3 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  4 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_intel          57344  7
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
soundwire_intel        45056  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_soc_core          319488  5 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           32768  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec         176128  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core          110592  10 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               143360  12 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              49152  1 snd_pcm
snd                   110592  22 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

I think possibly I don't have the drivers for my in-built microphone, or maybe my laptop thinks that my earbuds have a microhpone on them and something with pin configuration is messing up. I would appreciate any help!!

Comment: It's best to put the output of `arecord -l` into the question as text. Also, I'm not entirely certain what your question is? I suppose it is "how do I make the audio work?"

Comment: Yes both my audio and microphone are broken... so I want to get them working

Thanks for the comment, I will convert the arecord -l into text

Comment: Does the microphone work without the earbuds? What does the earphones jack connector look like?

Comment: Hi @tukan it doesn't work without the earbuds and in fact says that there is no microphone selectable in the settings (ahh so maybe my system cannot detect my computer's microphone? will look into this) 

The connector is a 3 stripe 2.50 mm audio jack I believe.

Comment: Also recently I tried plugging in an external microphone through an amp and it also doesn't detect input from this external microphone

Comment: Maybe dirty connector? If it is 3 stripe, then the earbuds have their mic.. As you said perhaps the internal mic. is not detected.

Comment: Is the kernel module list with or wothout the earbuds  plugged?

Comment: kernel module list is with earbuds plugged

I suppose the connector could be a problem but I don't think the earbuds have a mic. Trying to figure out how the internal mic might not be detected because I think I have the requisite drivers all installed

Answer (score 0):

You say that this is "since downloading Debian 11", did it work before?

Guess: Something changed in the realtek codec module, potentially some quirk handling. If you can dual-boot (or USB-boot) to an older Debian where it worked before, compare

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*
```

between the two and see if any codec settings have changed that potentially misconfigure the codec, so it enables some internal loopback or messes up some internal mixers.

If you cannot get a working version to compare, you need to hand-analyze the codec output to see if and where anything goes wrong.

The Debian `alsa-tools` package contains an utility called `hda-verb` which can be used to directly manipulate the codec, if necessary.